# Animated graphs in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, pandas-groupby

I have a table,

```
runs  opposition  date 
10  team A  01 aug 2020
23  team B  13 sep 1975
76  team C  03 Jan 1999 
92  team A  01 aug 1982 
12  team C  01 aug 2020 
100  team B  01 aug 2008 
83  team A  01 aug 2005 
93  team B  01 aug 2006 
23  team B  01 aug 2011 
11  team A  01 aug 2019
```

I want to plot a animated graph which will animated based on dates, teams, runs (addition of runs for teams)

note : probably I would like to create animated graphs like https://pythonawesome.com/animated-plotting-extension-for-pandas-with-matplotlib/

How can we plot such animated graph for table or df?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to achieve this without using the library that you have given as an example?

Comment: yes that library or any other library which can give animated graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an animation using the pandas_alive mentioned in the question. I'm using an extension of your sample data, which I can't post due to the large gif image size, but you can try running it in your own environment.

```
pip install pandas_alive # import 

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas_alive

names = ['team A','team B','team C','team E', 'team F']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2020-05-01','2021-11-01', freq='1m'),
                  'name': random.choices(names, k=18),
                  'runs': np.random.randint(0,150,18)})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df = df.pivot(columns='name')
df.columns = df.columns.droplevel()
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df = df.cumsum()

df.head()
name    team A  team B  team C  team E  team F
date                    
2020-05-31  92.0    0.0     0.0     0.0     0.0
2020-06-30  92.0    123.0   0.0     0.0     0.0
2020-07-31  92.0    123.0   0.0     140.0   0.0
2020-08-31  92.0    123.0   0.0     150.0   0.0
2020-09-30  92.0    123.0   0.0     150.0   133.0

def current_total(values):
    total = values.sum()
    s = f'Total : {int(total)}'
    return {'x': .85, 'y': .2, 's': s, 'ha': 'right', 'size': 11}

df.fillna(0).plot_animated('test_animate.gif', period_fmt='%Y-%m', title='Test Bar chart race', period_summary_func=current_total)
```

[image]

Comment: That looks quite interesting but a couple of changes like team total runs has to be increased and animation has to be little slow.

Comment: If there is an element you would like to add, please update the question and we will update the question to the extent we can handle it.

Comment: There is not any addition but the same requirement as mentioned in the question. Just 2 things left, first is runs are not getting added as shown in example link and animation is too fast.

Comment: The total can be handled by introducing the example function in the link, and I have updated the code and image. As for the animation speed, from the [source code](https://github.com/JackMcKew/pandas_alive/blob/main/pandas_alive/_base_chart.py), it reads as if it depends on the number of data and the time period.

Comment: Its still not adding the runs. Runs bar should increase with addition. Bar only shows single run score. Please check the reference link attached with question.

Comment: So it's not a cumulative value. I have updated the code and graph.

Comment: great, you are a good coder.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [plotly animation](https://plotly.com/python/animations/)

```py
fig = px.scatter(df, x="date", y="runs", animation_frame="opposition")
fig.update_traces(marker_size=40) # increase marker size
fig.write_html("fig.html") # export as html file
```

This gives you (only static image here...):

[image]

Comment: There will be only 3 teams and scores will be inceasing based on timelines

Comment: You can change the `x`, `y` and the animation frame according to your wishes.